# Extract values in regex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract the first 4 values ​​and the last 2 values ​​of a variable using regular expressions (regex).

```
const x = 405023

y = 4050
z = 23
```

I need to use this separation only one line (substr not working):

```
moment(`${this.$route.query.competencia.substr(0,4)}-${this.$route.query.competencia.substr(4,2)}`).format()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with regex?

Comment: @VLAZ compatibility browsers

Comment: This doesn't explain anything.

Comment: You could just use mathematics!

Comment: @phuzi or very basic string manipulation, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `match()`

```js
const x = 405023;
var r = x.toString().match(/\d{4}|\d{1,}/g);
var y = Number(r[0]);
var z = Number(r[1])
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Update for string:

```js
const x = 'HelloWorld';
var r = x.match(/.{5}|.{1,}/g);
var y = r[0];
var z = r[1];
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: These ways teach you to extract numbers, but what if there were letters?

Comment: @rbrt, please check the second answer with string...

Answer (score 1):

The value you have is not a string, you could use some rudimentary mathematics:

```js
const x = 405023

let z = x % 100;
let y = (x - z) / 100;

console.log('y:', y);
console.log('z:', z);
```

Comment: These ways teach you to extract numbers, but what if there were letters?

Comment: @rbrt you'd use string manipulation.

Comment: Then x would be a string not a number and you would use `'405323'.substr(0, 4)` and `.substr(4, 2)`

Comment: @phuzi I receive a query number in the format 202002 (date yyyydd), I need to separate the year from the month and turn them into a date:

Example:
moment (`$ {this. $ route.query.competencia.substr (0.4)} - $ {this. $ route.query.competencia.substr (4.2)}`) .format ()

Using substr is not being recognized, I tried all of the above but it didn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: if `substr` is not being recognised, then you likely have a number and string manipulation is not the way to do it and regular expressions won't work (unless you convert the number to a string first. Just go with the mathematical way in my answer and you'll be fine (so long as it is a number that you're getting).